# Azure Webjob returning 400 Bad request when inserting into table storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-webjobs, azure-table-storage

I'm having the same issue as [Azure table storage returns 400 Bad Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859405/azure-table-storage-returns-400-bad-request), but only when deploying the webjob. When running it locally towards the same queues and table storage it works fine. As soon as I deploy it to azure it wont run and returning 400 Bad Request when I check the log stream.

- I've checked all DateTime properties, and they should be fine now.
- I'm doing checks that the table exists.
- No special characters in partition or row key.
- Insertion operation is InsertOrReplace.

Object structure:

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the data you're trying to enter in the table. As mentioned in the answer you linked, 400 error is caused because of user error.

Comment: http://imgur.com/T72tpUq

This is the object structure.

Comment: I edited your question to include your image (please don't embed these in comments). At this point you should edit your question to show the pertinent snippet of code. A bit difficult to tell what's happening without seeing what you're actually doing.

Comment: Please try to capture the `StorageException` and log the detailed error of `StorageException.RequestInformation.ExtendedErrorInformation` when deploying to Azure. With the detailed error, we could locate this issue.

Comment: Yeah can you add the revelant code